# Is the paper provided by a physician indicating a patient should do an MRI without referring any business referred to as a prescription or a referral?

Tags: word-choice

Is the paper provided by a physician indicating a patient should do an MRI without mentioning any medical imaging business referred to as a prescription or a referral? Or perhaps it is named differently (maybe "lab order")?

According to Wiktionary:

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prescription:  A written order, as by a physician or nurse practitioner, for the administration of a medicine or other intervention.
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/referral: referral = the act or process of transferring someone or something to another, of sending by reference, or referring.

None of these two definitions apply to the paper as an MRI isn't a "medicine or other intervention" and the paper doesn't refer to anyone.

---

Example of such paper on which the physician ordered some MRI to a patient ([source](https://redd.it/77nhr9)):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the form in the example post, it is a prescription.

Incidentally, this example prescription does specify that the patient receive a medicine:  The "contrast" material needs to be in the patient's body when the MRI is performed.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps the word "prescription" is part of the form template because most commonly the form is used to prescribed pharmaceutical drugs?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt -- Yes.